# suppress "listening for transport dt_socket" message when remote debugging Java programs

Tags: java, remote-debugging

Is there an option for the `-agentlib:jdwp` argument that causes the `listening for transport` message not to be printed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the `quiet=y` option. A complete example would look like this:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8001,suspend=n,quiet=y {YOUR_APP_HERE}
```

You can find out about all options via

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=help
```